# Generic test template missing from Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I'm porting a console app written in C++ from *NIX to Windows. I'm using Visual Studio 2010 Professional for my development environment. We have an existing Perl script that runs dozens of tests exercising all of the command line options, so I'd like to include a test that runs that perl script as part of our solution. I'm new to the testing features in Visual Studio, but a little reading seemed to indicate that a 'Generic Test' should be what I want.

However, when I step through the Generic Test [instructions in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182624.aspx), no "Generic Test" template is available when I choose "Add" for my test project. I see "Unit test" and "Ordered Test", but no "Generic Test". If I look in the common7/IDE/ItemTemplates I can templates for "BasicUnitTest", "OrderedTest", "SimpleUnitTest", and "UnitTestWizard". A broader search doesn't find any sign of "GenericTest".

I'm stumped. Any suggestions on what I should try next?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [features for the various editions of Visual Studio](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions) it looks like VS Professional only supports unit tests. If I want GenericTest I'll have to pay for the premium or ultimate edition :(